# using href to get to specific part making menu disappear?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to get a user to click on a link which takes them to a specfic point on a page. I have got it working but my menu dissapears. I think my css is incorrect. I have copied the code and tried to replicate in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uzi002/tuD7J/4/) example as much as poss.

Comment: It seems to be working right and the menu has to disappear cause you are scrolling the page to get down to the part of the page you clicked on.

Comment: but you can not scroll back up to the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your nav bar (.menu-link) a position of fixed which will always keep it at the top of the screen on top of everything else (once you give it a z-index)). You'd then probably want to add a top margin to your other content so that when users scroll back to the top they don't lose the content under the nav bar.

Here's a fork of your **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JbGRB/)**. BTW, you might want to remove the overflow hidden so that the scrollbars return.

Comment: there is a scroll in the right panel thats the only scroll i would like

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking to do now. Could you explain further?